# How to plot several images on one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to do it because it will be useful for making "picture plots" in R.

What I want to see, e.g.:

[image]

I have one solution from "boshek" with using `ggimage`, but it is a little limited.

I tried to make it with `plotly`.

```
 no_axis <- list(
           title = "",
           zeroline = FALSE,
           showline = FALSE,
           showticklabels = FALSE,
           showgrid = FALSE
      )
 plot_ly() %>%
     layout(title = 'Quantity of cars in West Europe countries', xaxis = no_axes, yaxis = no_axes, 
         images = list(
             source = "https://jeroen.github.io/images/superfrink.gif",
             x = 1, y = 0.5, 
             sizex = 3, sizey = 2,
             xref = "x", yref = "y", 
             xanchor = "left", yanchor = "bottom"
         )
     )
```

I could add only one pic and couldn't append labels with text.

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://davetang.org/muse/2019/02/22/importing-vector-images-into-r/

Comment: @bloxx interesting. but it implies using of two apps. I thought, that exists a package with standard symbols (car, man, house, ship etc.) and instruments for making similar visuals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A super basic implementation but the `ggimage` package is your friend here:

```r
library(ggimage)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats) ## to reorder the labels

d <- data.frame(
  height = c(150, 350, 950),
  x = c("Luxembourg", "Spain", "France"), y = 1
)

## whatever you want
img <- "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"

ggplot(d, aes(x = fct_reorder(x, height), y = y)) +
  geom_image(aes(
    image = img,
    size = I(height / 1000)
  ), by = "height") +
  labs(title = " Quantity of cars in West Europe Countries") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text())
```

[image]